# Help OP to start bounty

Tags: support, bounty

Can we help an OP to start a bounty on their question?

Last time I saw there was a "start a bounty" link below the OP's post, but now I can't see it.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can only bounty a question if it is at least 48 hours old.

Comment: @S.L.Barth It already more than that. Example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966508/bitmap-to-base-64-encode-string

Comment: The OP needs to have the bounty privilege. Without that they can't

Comment: I am able to see the bounty link on that question @JohnJoe maybe you have some extension messing with the page?

Comment: I see a "start a bounty" link on that one - below the comments.

Comment: Oh thanks, maybe I have some extension messing with the page like what @Hoi_A said

Comment: It will be pushed under **Comments** Check it there

Comment: @SagarV yup, saw it.Thanks

Comment: Does "question eligible for bounty **in** 5 hours" mean "question eligible for bounty **after** 5 hours"?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho I think yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only start a bounty on a question if it is at least 48 hours old.

Even then, the bounty link will be *below* the commments.

[image]

You can use that link to add a bounty, if you have the privilege and have enough reputation points.

If you want the OP to add a bounty from their own points - you can tell them how it works. That's about all you can do. After that, it's up to them if they want to spend their points on a bounty. (And in this particular case, the OP doesn't have enough points to start a bounty).

For completeness sake, you could theoretically upvote their posts so that they have enough rep to post a bounty. But that is extremely improper - voting should be done to indicate that a post is good, not to give or take rep.

Comment: we can't help then to bounty a question ? I can click that link

Comment: @JohnJoe You can bounty it yourself. You can't really help the OP to start a bounty from their own points. You can tell them how it works, but that's all. (And in this particular case, the OP doesn't have enough rep to start a bounty).