# Missing "start a bounty" link

Tags: support, bounty

Does "question eligible for bounty **in** 5 hours" mean "question eligible for bounty **after** 5 hours"?

I found a comment like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346013/help-op-to-start-bounty):
*Off the top of my head, you can only bounty a question if it is at least 48 hours old*.

Should I wait and relax or start worry because having 5 hours left to find out how to do?

There is no *"start a bounty" link*. CTRL+F find only the link *question eligible for bounty **in** 5 hours*. Clicking that it then say somewhere:

*To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question ...*

Comment: so,  uh, in 5 hours, you can start the bounty. Reading a help doc that says there's a start a bounty button at the bottom of an eligible question doesn't change that... your question isn't eligible for one for another 5 hours...

Comment: Why is the bounty link missing?

Comment: It will not show up until the question is eligible, what exactly is the confusion here?

Comment: Because my swedish brain interprets **in** as **within**. And eligible means I am allowed for a bounty within 5 hours. But I found a comment say:  *you can only bounty a question if it is at least 48 hours old*

Comment: "in" == "om", "within" == "inom". Hope that clears up the use of the words. =)

Comment: Sorry for min engelska

Comment: There is [English.se] where part of the question discussing meaning of "in" may be more appropriate... Personally I'd avoid making any parallels between "in"/"by"/"off" in English and literal translation to your native language - the chance to get meaning right is just too low :)

Comment: No no - I made a parallell with "to be in time"

Comment: The parallell "in" == "om"? I would here translate the swedish word "om" to "after"/"about" and not "by"/"off". That means *Bounty is eligible in 5 hours* = *Bounty eligible after 5 hours*

Comment: If the logic of *eligible in 5 hours* is meaning after 5 hours, then how do you all explain these statements found by Google: *John can complete a piece of work in 10 hours*, *fill a certain order in 10 hours*, *Crane A can unload a ship in 10 hours*... Try solve this with "the bounty logic": https://www.wyzant.com/resources/answers/161909/sofia_can_type_the_work_in_10_hours_noga_can_do_it_in_15_hours_they_work_together_for_4_hours_then_sofia_left_and_noga_finished_the_job_how_long_did_it_take

Comment: I am not a confusion lover so I propose to change *question eligible for bounty in xx hours* to something more logic. But this would be an improvement :(

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, your link was extremely imprecise as a reference to *discussing meaning of "in"* but maybe these kind of confusions make you popular?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho could you please clarify what link you expect to suggest an SE site appropriate for particular question? (Granted https://ell.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate for "what 'in five hours' means" if you want to spin it as learning exercise, but I don't get why you said the link to the site's home page is bad way to link to a site).

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho (I pretend that  have not seen the second part of your comment, but be careful with personal attacks on meta or main site) - you probably can flag all my comments as "no longer necessary" when you read them, definitely this one. Or you can mark this as "not kind" if you feel so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no "start a bounty" link. CTRL+F find only the link question
> eligible for bounty in 5 hours. Clicking that it then say somewhere:

That mean your question was asked not more than 2 days(48 hours). You need to wait for 5 more hours to bounty your question.

You can find more info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> **How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.